# Почему пустой массив при объединении значений?

Tags: javascript

```js
var arr = [];
data = [
  {id: 1, base: "Yes", name: "Test 1"},
  {id: 2, base: "No", name: "Test 2"},
  {id: 2, base: "Yes", name: "Test 3"},
  {id: 4, base: "No", name: "Test 4"},
];
$.each(data, function(i, item){
  if(arr[item.base]) arr[item.base].push(item.name);
  else arr[item.base] = [];
});
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Нужен примерно такой результат

```
[
  "Yes" [
    "Test 1",
    "Test 3"
  ],
  "No" [
    "Test 2",
    "Test 4"
  ]
]
```

Comment: какой результат вы хотели получить?

Comment: @nörbörnën, добавил в вопрос

Comment: в js нет структуры, которая была бы похожа на это

Comment: @nörbörnën, это просто пример, нужен многоуровневый массив, в js есть такое, может просто не так пишется

Comment: всем будет удобнее, если вы поясните задачу javascript-овыми словами. пока вы просто предлагаете угадать что именно вам нужно

Comment: @nörbörnën Необходимо сгруппировать значения в массиве `data` по значению ключа `base`.

Comment: @MoloF в объект или в массив масивов? так? `var arr = data.reduce((acc, x) => ((acc[x.base] || (acc[x.base] = [])).push(x.name)) && acc, {});`

Comment: @nörbörnën оно самое, оставьте воспроизводимый ответ чтобы можно было проголосовать за вас

Comment: @nörbörnën, Спасибо, как раз то что нужно. А как можно его дополнить, отсортировать по base и по name, по алфавиту возрастанию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство массива `length` меняется **только** при добавлении/удалении ключей, которые могут быть допустимыми индексами, а именно целочисленные значения от 0 до 2<sup>32</sup>

В данном случае в массив добавляются строковые ключи, которые не влияют на свойство `length`.

В данном случае `arr` нужно заменить на объект, тогда и вывод будет ожидаемым:

```js
var arr = {};
data = [{
    id: 1,
    base: "Yes",
    name: "Test 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    base: "No",
    name: "Test 2"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    base: "Yes",
    name: "Test 3"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    base: "No",
    name: "Test 4"
  },
];
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  if (arr[item.base]) arr[item.base].push(item.name);
  else arr[item.base] = [item.name];
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```